# sql parameter on http links

Tags: java, android, sql, http

i'm developping an android application that need to browse a MySQL Database. 
I've suceeded on getting a infortion when i want all information on a table, the probleme is, when i want to add parameter like `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Name=name` i dont know how to add he parameter on the HTTP link.
This is the link to get all Countries " http://cookndinner.atwebpages.com/api/countries " this one works well ( you can try it ) but when i want to select a country going by Code = Fr with this sql request `SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES WHERE CODE=FR` it doesnt work.

I tried this link :  http://cookndinner.atwebpages.com/api/countries/

this one : http://cookndinner.atwebpages.com/api/countries/FR

and this one : http://cookndinner.atwebpages.com/api/countries/code=FR

none of it are working, and it just give all information on the table and doesn't add the parameter

I also trid this one for another table : http://cookndinner.atwebpages.com/api/users?email=louisard2@gmail.com&password=bankai123
 but it's not working either

COuld someone help me and indicate how to insert SQL Parameter on Http links pls or if you know a tutorial that may be useful

Thank you

PS : the php part is already done

Comment: What is "a infortion" ?!?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the beginning, make sure your query in PHP looks like this:

```
$code = $_GET['code'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM countries WHERE code = '$code'");
```

Then your URI should look like this:

```
String url_get_country = "http://yourHostName/nameOfPhPFile.php?code=" + code
```

You can pass code as a parameter in method. If this doesn't work, you can change the SQL query to ...

```
... where code like '$code'
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for uour answer,i tried it like this  : "http://cookndinner.atwebpages.com/api/countries?code=FR"    where nameOfPhPFile = api/countries, but it still doen'st work  for the php part i'm not the who it but i'm pretty sure it's well done

Comment: Well, in order to build URI you need to know  descriptor and parameters and that's all. Just ask person responsible for the PHP part and he will give you the answer